# Can $\|f\| = \|a\|_{q}$ to arbitrary values of $p$ and $q$ satisfying ${1 \over p} + {1 \over q} = 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

We all know that:

> > Suppose $a = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n})$ is a point in Euclide space $R^{n}$. Consider the mapping $f: R^{n} \rightarrow R$, $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}$. Then $\|f\| = \|a\|$.

So I wonder if we can make this to the general case like this:

> > Let ${1 \over p} + {1 \over q} = 1$, $p > 1$, $l_{p} = \{x = (\lambda_{k})_{k}: \sum_{k=1}^\infty|\lambda_{k}|^{p} < \infty\}$, $\|x\|_{p} = (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{k}|^{p})^{1 \over p}$. We define $a \in l_{p}$ and $f:l_{p} \rightarrow R$ like above (except the sum is countably infinite). Then is it right that $\|f\| = \|a\|_{q}$?

We can't use the way we prove for the case $p = q = 2$ in this general case. So I'm wondering whether this problem is right. If not, can we give a counter-example for this? Please help me clarify this. Thanks so much. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Using Holder inequlity you can show that $\Vert f\Vert\leq\Vert a\Vert_q$. Now consider 
$$
x=(|a_1|^{q-1}\operatorname{sign}(a_1),\ldots,|a_n|^{q-1}\operatorname{sign}(a_n))
$$ 
then $f(x)=\Vert a\Vert_q^q$ and $\Vert x\Vert_p=\Vert a\Vert_{q-1}^q$. So $\Vert f\Vert\geq |f(x)|/\Vert x\Vert_p=\Vert a\Vert_q$. From these inequalities it follows that $\Vert f\Vert=\Vert a\Vert_q$

Comment: How? With Hoelder inequality, we can only deduce that $||f|| \le ||a||_{q}$. How can we prove the the equality?

Comment: @leducquang see edits to my answer

Comment: awesome. Thanks so much Norbert.

Comment: @leducquang you are welcome!